# How can I create a stronger ETL Pipeline library?

Tags: python, api, etl

I've written a module for running ETL pipelines. The goal was to standardize API use in pipelines while making the pipeline easy to create and maintain. I'm not a Python guru by any means, and I'm wondering how I could continue improving this. It's not complete even by my standards yet, as I still need to clean up some parts of it... but I figure it's close enough to ask for some extra eyes on it.

```
import os
import re
import json
import warnings
from pandas import json_normalize
from pykeepass import PyKeePass
from schema import Schema, Hook, Or, Use, Optional, SchemaError, Forbidden
           
            
class Tasks_Manager():
    def _requests_schema(key, scope, error):
        Schema({Use(int):dict}, error=f"Key 'requests' must use "
               "<class 'int'> for its dict keys.").validate(scope[key])
        
    # Pipeline schema
    LINE_SCHEMA = Schema({
        Use(str) : {
            'api_handle' : object,
            'cred_title' : str,
            'tasks'      : {
                Use(str) : {
                    Or('request', 'requests', only_one=True): dict,
                    Hook('requests', handler=_requests_schema): object,
                    Optional(Use(str))  : object,
                    Forbidden('handle_response')  : object,
                    Forbidden('wrangle_response') : object,
                    Forbidden('error')            : object
                }
            },
            Optional('wrangler')    : object,
            Optional('task_kwargs') : dict,
            Optional('raw_tasks')   : dict # Added by program. NOT USER.
        }
    })
    
    
    def __init__(self):           
        self.pipeline = None
        self.results  = None

    
    # Retrieves credentials
    def get_credentials(self, title):
        # Get environment variables
        keyfile  = os.getenv('keepass_keyfile')
        key      = str(os.getenv('keepass_key'))
        database = os.getenv('keepass_directory')

        # Returns DB instance
        cred_manager = PyKeePass(database, password=key, keyfile=keyfile)
        credentials  = cred_manager.find_entries(title=title, first=True)
        
        return credentials
    
    
    # Handles loading of tasks
    def load_tasks(self, path, kwargs):
        
        # Hook to check for dynamic strings
        def json_hook(pairs):
            
            # Hook for in-string variables
            def reg_hook(match):   
                if not match.group(1) in kwargs:
                    raise ValueError(
                        f'"{match.group(1)}" was dynamically entered '
                        f'but no value was specified for this key.\n'
                        f'Fields include: {kwargs}'
                    )
                else:
                    return kwargs[match.group(1)]
                    
            
            # Performs d-type specific comprehension replacement
            for key, val in pairs.items():
                    pairs[key] = json.loads(
                        re.sub(r'{{(.*?)}}', reg_hook, json.dumps(val))
                    )

            return pairs

        # Returns the filled doc, no nulls
        with open(path) as file:
            return json.load(
                file,
                object_hook=json_hook
            )
        
        
    # Creates an object for holding results
    def get_results_obj(self, pipes):
        # Creates dict to hold results
        results_object = dict()

        # Elements of results obj not found in
        # pipeline; to be added
        client_res = {
            'client' : None,
            'error'  : None
        }
        _task_res = {
            'handle_response'  : None,
            'error'            : None
        }

        # Iters through pipes for creation of results obj
        for pipe, pipe_dict in pipes.items():
            task_res = _task_res.copy()
            
            # Adds wrangle response if wrangler provided
            if pipe_dict.get('wrangler'):
                task_res.update({'wrangle_response':None})
            
            # Objects for filling in results dict
            tasks = pipe_dict['tasks']
            tasks_res = dict(
                {_id: task|task_res for _id, task in tasks.items()}
            )

            # Cleans for new results dict
            pipe_dict = pipe_dict.copy()|client_res
            pipe_dict.pop('api_handle')
            pipe_dict.pop('wrangler', None)

            # Adds pipe to new results dict
            results_object[pipe] = dict.fromkeys(pipe_dict)

            # Provides pipe-part specific cleansings
            for pipe_part, part_dict in pipe_dict.items():
                results_object[pipe][pipe_part] = (
                    tasks_res if pipe_part == 'tasks'
                    else part_dict if pipe_part == 'raw_tasks'
                    else part_dict if pipe_part == 'cred_title'
                    else None
                )
        
        return results_object
            
    
    # Collects data from client handle
    def get_handle_response(client, request):
        return client.get_data(request)
        
        
    # Runs tasks
    def run_request(self, request, client):
        error            = None
        
        # Requests data
        handle_response = client.get_data(request)

        # Skips iter and logs error if true
        if client.last_result != 'pass':
            error = dict(
                step  = 'data request',
                error = client.error,
                trace = client.traceback
            )
            
        return handle_response, error
    
    
    # Runs wrangles
    def run_wrangler(self, task, wrangler):
        error            = None
        
        # Performs wrangle
        wrangle_response = wrangler.wrangle(task)
        
        # Logs error if error
        if wrangler.last_result != 'pass':
            error = dict(
                step  = 'data wrangle', 
                error = wrangler.error,
                trace = wrangler.traceback
            )
            
        return wrangle_response, error
    
        
    def run_tasks(self, tasks, client, results_object, wrangler=None):
        # Hook for in-string variables
        def reg_hook(match):   
            if not match.group(1) in last_response.columns:
                raise ValueError(
                    f'"{match.group(1)}" was dynamically entered '
                    f'but was not found in the prior response.\n'
                    f'Fields include: {last_response.columns}'
                )
            else:
                return str(
                    last_response[match.group(1)].unique().tolist()
                    if form == 'list' 
                    else tuple(last_response[match.group(1)].unique().tolist())
                )
        
        # For each task
        for t_id, task_dict in tasks.items():
            request  = task_dict.get('request', dict())
            requests = task_dict.get('requests', dict())
            
            # Verifies cant be both
            assert bool(request)+bool(requests) == 1
            
            # For mono-request tasks
            if request:
                # Performs request
                handle_response, error = self.run_request(request, client)
                
                # Updates results
                results_object['tasks'][t_id]['handle_response'] = handle_response
                results_object['tasks'][t_id]['error'] = error
            
            # For multi-request tasks
            elif requests:
                # Mutates handle response to match requests ids
                results_object['tasks'][t_id]['handle_response'] = dict.fromkeys(
                   requests
                )
                
                # For each request
                last_response = None
                for r_id, request in requests.items():
                    
                    # Allows request param to specify injection format as list
                    # Else tuple is default
                    form = 'not specified'
                    if request.get('inject_format'):
                        form = request.pop('inject_format').lower()
                        
                        # Warns user that tuple will be used
                        if form not in ['tuple', 'list']:
                            warnings.warn(
                                f'{form} is invalid. Use "list" if desired. '
                                'Otherwise, a tuple will be supplied.'
                            )   
                            
                    # Allows specified last response columns to be added to next response
                    if last_response is not None:
                        request = json.loads(
                        re.sub(r'<<(.*?)>>', reg_hook, json.dumps(request))
                    )
                        
                    # Performs request & logs last response for use in next iteration
                    handle_response, error = self.run_request(request, client)
                    last_response = json_normalize(handle_response)
                    
                    # Updates results
                    results_object['tasks'][t_id]['handle_response'][r_id] = handle_response
                    results_object['tasks'][t_id]['error'] = error
                    
                    # Any error causes full break
                    if error:
                        break  
                        
            # Don't wrangle if error occured
            if error:
                continue

            # Runs wrangler only if wrangler provided
            elif wrangler:
                # Performs wrangle
                wrangle_response, error = self.run_wrangler(
                    results_object['tasks'][t_id], wrangler)
                
                # Logs result of wrangle
                results_object['tasks'][t_id]['wrangle_response'] = wrangle_response
                results_object['tasks'][t_id]['error'] = error
                    
        return results_object
        
        
    # Runs pipes
    def run_pipes(self, pipes, results_object):
        for pipe, pipe_dict in pipes.items():
            api_handle  = pipe_dict['api_handle']
            cred_title  = pipe_dict['cred_title']
            tasks       = pipe_dict['tasks']
            wrangler    = pipe_dict.get('wrangler')
            res_object  = results_object[pipe]
            
            # Retrieves credentials and initializes client
            credentials = self.get_credentials(cred_title)
            client      = api_handle(credentials)

            # Logs result of authenticating client
            res_object.update(client = client.status)
            
            # Checks status of client authentication
            if client.status == 'pass':
                # Runs tasks
                res_object = self.run_tasks(
                    tasks          = tasks, 
                    client         = client,
                    results_object = res_object,
                    wrangler       = wrangler
                ) 
                # Logs result
                results_object[pipe] = res_object
                
            # Skips iter and logs error if true 
            else:
                results_object[pipe].update(
                    error = dict(
                        step  = 'client', 
                        err   = client.error,
                        trace = client.traceback
                    )
                )
                continue 
                
        return results_object

    
    # Runs the pipes of a pipeline
    def run_pipeline(self, pipeline, kwargs=None):    
        # Updates attributes
        self.pipeline = pipeline
        
        for pipe, pipe_dict in pipeline.items():
            tasks = pipe_dict['tasks']
            
            # If path provided, loads tasks
            if isinstance(tasks, str):
                
                # Reads the document in
                with open(tasks) as file:
                    pipe_dict['raw_tasks'] = json.load(file)
                
                # Reads document again, with hooks to complete request
                pipe_dict['tasks'] = self.load_tasks(
                    pipe_dict['tasks'],
                    pipe_dict['task_kwargs']
                )
        
        # Validates schema, will throw error
        type(self).LINE_SCHEMA.validate(self.pipeline)
                
        # Vars
        results_object = self.get_results_obj(pipeline)
        
        # Runs the pipes & Records result
        self.results = self.run_pipes( 
            pipeline, 
            results_object
        )
        
        return self.results
    
    
def load_tasks(path, kwargs):
    return Tasks_Manager().load_tasks(path, kwargs)
```

A pipeline might be created like this:

```
# Creates pipeline object
pipeline = dict()

start = '2022-12-23'
end   = '2022-12-29'

from pipes.google_analytics4.ga4_handle import Google_Analytics4
from pipes.google_analytics4.ga4_wrangler import GA4_Wrangler

# Adds to pipeline
pipeline.update(
    # Creates pipe object
    ga4_pipe = dict(
        api_handle  = Google_Analytics4,
        cred_title  = 'GA4',
        tasks       = r'pipes\google_analytics4\ga4_tasks.json',
        task_kwargs = dict(start_date=start, end_date=end),
        wrangler    = GA4_Wrangler()
    )
)

from pipes.google_ads.g_ads_handle import Google_Ads
from pipes.google_ads.g_ads_wrangler import G_Ads_Wrangler

# Adds to pipeline
pipeline.update(
    # Creates pipe object
    gads_pipe = dict(
        api_handle  = Google_Ads,
        cred_title  = 'Ads',
        tasks       = r'pipes\google_ads\g_ads_tasks.json',
        task_kwargs = dict(start_date=start, end_date=end),
        wrangler    = G_Ads_Wrangler()
    )
)

from task_manager import Tasks_Manager as tm

task_manager = tm()
res = task_manager.run_pipeline(
    pipeline
)
```

It uses KeePass for credentials, JSON files for "tasks", and classes with predefined attributes for API handles and "wranglers". It also uses hooks when reading in the JSON tasks and can use KWArgs to dynamically set any substrings wrapped in {{ }}. It will also parse substrings wrapped in << >> as variables that are retrieved from the previous API call.

Here's an example "task":

```
{
    "1": {
        "requests": {
            "1": {
                "customer_id": "5772948104",
                "query": "SELECT geographic_view.country_criterion_id, metrics.clicks, campaign.name, campaign.advertising_channel_type, metrics.impressions, metrics.cost_micros, segments.date FROM geographic_view WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '{{start_date}}' AND '{{end_date}}'"
            },
            "2": {
                "customer_id": "5772948104",
                "query": "SELECT geo_target_constant.canonical_name, geo_target_constant.id FROM geo_target_constant WHERE geo_target_constant.id IN <<geographic_view.country_criterion_id>>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and here's another example:

```
{
    "1": {
        "measure_name": "visitors",
        "request": {
            "property": "properties/324294012", 
            "date_ranges": [{"start_date": "{{start_date}}", "end_date": "{{end_date}}"}], 
            "dimensions": [
                {"name": "sessionSource"}, 
                {"name": "sessionMedium"}, 
                {"name": "sessionDefaultChannelGroup"},
                {"name": "country"},
                {"name": "date"}
            ], 
            "metrics": [
                {"name": "totalUsers"},
                {"name": "bounceRate"}
            ], 
            "dimension_filter": {
                "and_group": {
                    "expressions": [
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "hostname", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "CONTAINS", 
                                    "value": "mycompany.com"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "sessionSource", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "pageReferrer", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "measure_name": "downloads_desktop",
        "request": {
            "property": "properties/324294012", 
            "date_ranges": [{"start_date": "{{start_date}}", "end_date": "{{end_date}}"}], 
            "dimensions": [
                {"name": "sessionSource"}, 
                {"name": "sessionMedium"}, 
                {"name": "sessionDefaultChannelGroup"},
                {"name": "country"},
                {"name": "date"}
            ], 
            "metrics": [
                {"name": "totalUsers"}
            ], 
            "dimension_filter": {
                "and_group": {
                    "expressions": [
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "hostname", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "CONTAINS", 
                                    "value": "mycompany.com"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "sessionSource", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "pageReferrer", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "eventName", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "EXACT", 
                                    "value": "file_download"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "fileName", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                    "value": "(?i).*(share\\-app).*(?-i)"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "measure_name": "ad_visits",
        "request": {
            "property": "properties/324294012", 
            "date_ranges": [{"start_date": "{{start_date}}", "end_date": "{{end_date}}"}], 
            "dimensions": [
                {"name": "sessionSource"}, 
                {"name": "sessionMedium"}, 
                {"name": "sessionDefaultChannelGroup"},
                {"name": "country"},
                {"name": "date"}
            ], 
            "metrics": [
                {"name": "totalUsers"}
            ], 
            "dimension_filter": {
                "and_group": {
                    "expressions": [
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "hostname", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "CONTAINS", 
                                    "value": "mycompany.com"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "sessionSource", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not_expression" : {
                                "filter": {
                                    "field_name": "pageReferrer", 
                                    "string_filter": {
                                        "match_type": "FULL_REGEXP", 
                                        "value": "(?i).*(unbounce|heatmap|localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1|mycompany|go\\.|tagassistant).*(?-i)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "field_name": "eventName", 
                                "string_filter": {
                                    "match_type": "EXACT", 
                                    "value": "try_for_free"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "measure_name": "organicGoogleSearch",
        "request": {
            "property": "properties/324294012", 
            "date_ranges": [{"start_date": "{{start_date}}", "end_date": "{{end_date}}"}], 
            "dimensions": [
                {"name": "country"},
                {"name": "date"}
            ], 
            "metrics": [
                {"name": "organicGoogleSearchClicks"},
                {"name": "organicGoogleSearchImpressions"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any feedback on the design. I'd really like to know where the biggest areas for improvement area.

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite a while to understand your code. I think some restructuring and improved naming might benefit the readability (and later on maintainability) of your code.

## Errors

There are somethings not completely right in your code:

- Some of the functions in your class miss a self argument. Most of these seem to be methods that are static and do not depends on the class object. You can move these function outside of the class or annotate them with `@staticmethod`.
- Your `error` can, code technically, be uninitialized before use. Sometimes this is not possible in practice, but such cases are always good to carefully consider and it might be worth restructuring/changing the code to avoid this.

I would recommend using a developer environment, which will pick up such problems for you. It will also pick up on formatting issues your code has.

## General layout

You currently have a single class and put everything under that. I think that is not the optimal organization. Your code is about running pipelines and managing tasks is more a side-effect of doing this.

Besides pipelines I discern a few more 'entities' in your code: pipes and tasks. It took me quite a while to understand how everything was connected (pipelines contain pipes, which in turn contain tasks). Currently, every entity you have in your code is a Python dictionary. These dictionaries are powerful tools, but in this case I believe this hampers readability.

I would create several new classes, `Pipeline`, `Pipe` and either `Task` or `SingleRequestTask` and `MultipleRequestTask`. I would start moving the functionality you currently have in `TaskManager` to the relevant classes and get rid of that class all together. You might also consider using a separate file for some utility functions/classes, for example for handling credentials or perhaps code that can be re-used for doing the requests.

Other than in some other languages there is no need to put everything in a class and your organization also depends on your preference. You could either use functions directly in a module to interact with the Pipeline, Pipe and Task classes and treat these classes like data types or you could put the functionality in the classes themselves. Just be consistent in what you choose.

## Approach

It would be good to split up loading the pipeline and running the pipeline. Right now you load your tasks just before running them. This might not be desirable: what if you have a pipeline with 8 pipes and the first 7 succeed, but the last one fails on a invalid task definition file? I do not know your exact use case or the specifics of these pipelines, but you might need to rerun the whole pipeline later after fixing the problem after spending time and money on the first 7 steps for nothing.

There is also another upside to finishing building the pipeline first and combination with using classes for your entities: you can get rid of your schema verification and just fill in the fields of your classes and do verification (if needed) there.

## Readability

### Comments/documentation

My recommendation would be to get rid of most of your comments and replace them by using good names for your functions and variables or if they really contain important information that is not obvious from the code you can add them to doc strings, which is very important if this code will function like some kind of library. https://www.askpython.com/python/python-docstring

There are a few downsides to having so many small and often quite obvious comments in your code:

- Often it is just as easy to read the code as the comment, but now you need to read both and the more lines of code to read, the longer it will take. Also, less code will be on your screen at the same time, making more scrolling necessary.
- While you are working on the code, it is easy to forget changing comments you have added before, which might make the comments actually hurt your code.

I personally use comments to make a 'to do list' for myself while developing, and remove the comments after I actually implemented the functionality. Most of in code comments that are left after development are things that might surprise someone who knows Python, for example explaining that we use a strange looking workaround due to a bug.

### Types

If you want this code to be like a library, which others may work on/with or if you want to make use of the type checking some developer tools offer (such as PyCharm), you can add type annotations.

## Pipeline definition

If I understand correctly, you want to create several pipeline definitions and have a common library for all these definitions with the actual code. Currently this part seems incomplete, but if these pipelines are supposed to be run from the command line, you might want to use the normal way to make a runnable Python script using `__main__`.

This is an example of how it might look (also with some other recommendations implemented that I described before):

```py
from pipes.google_ads.g_ads_handle import Google_Ads
from pipes.google_ads.g_ads_wrangler import G_Ads_Wrangler
from pipes.google_analytics4.ga4_handle import Google_Analytics4
from pipes.google_analytics4.ga4_wrangler import GA4_Wrangler

from src.etl_pipeline.pipeline import Pipeline, Pipe
from src.etl_pipeline.utilities import CredentialManager

START_DATE = '2022-12-23'
END_DATE = '2022-12-29'

credential_manager = CredentialManager()


pipeline = Pipeline(
    pipeline_id='Example pipeline',
    pipes=[
        Pipe(
            name='ga4_pipe',
            api_handle=Google_Analytics4,
            secret_id='GA4',
            tasks_file_path=r'pipes\google_analytics4\ga4_tasks.json',
            task_kwargs=dict(start_date=START_DATE, end_date=END_DATE),
            wrangler=GA4_Wrangler(),
            credential_manager=credential_manager
        ),
        Pipe(
            name='gads_pipe',
            api_handle=Google_Ads,
            secret_id='Ads',
            tasks_file_path=r'pipes\google_ads\g_ads_tasks.json',
            task_kwargs=dict(start_date=START_DATE, end_date=END_DATE),
            wrangler=G_Ads_Wrangler(),
            credential_manager=credential_manager
        )
    ]
)


def run_pipeline():
    pipeline_result = pipeline.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_pipeline()
```

## Conclusion and last thoughts

I think that if you restructure your code a bit, things become easier to understand and in my experience the code also starts to 'flow' easier and it becomes easy to decide what the correct location for functionality will be.

I tried to keep this advice to the most obvious first steps, but there are a few general tips:

- Try to keep all code in a function on the same level of abstraction. That makes a function easier to understand and follow. An example would be the function that runs a task. I would split the if/else logic from doing the actual requests for the tasks.
- Try to bring relatively cheap operations that can fail, such as reading a task definition JSON file, to the front of the execution.
- Dictionaries are powerful, but having dictionaries of dictionaries of dictionaries can sometimes make things hard to understand. There is also a point with might be personal preference, but you use dictionaries also when order is important. Only from Python 3.7 (from the top of my mind) is insertion ordering guaranteed, but I personally prefer to avoid dictionaries for ordered data. Consider using lists of tasks and pipes. I also believe that the JSON specification also does not require ordering of key, value pairs, just of lists. For now you are OK, but perhaps something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough reply. I've taken this information to the  heart of the design and applied some major changes. It's not done yet, but feel free to take a look: https://github.com/MrChadMWood/Pypeline/blob/main/Pypeline.py